# Install APC RedHat

Tags: php, redhat

i am trying to install apc on redhat so i did:

```
pecl install apc
```

i said **yes** to:

```
Use apxs to set compile flags (if using APC with Apache)? [yes]:
```

and i get this:

```
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.9.11 or later if you want to \
regenerate PHP parsers.
```

and

```
checking whether apc needs to get compiler flags from apxs...

Sorry, I was not able to successfully run APXS.  Possible reasons:

1.  Perl is not installed;
2.  Apache was not compiled with DSO support (--enable-module=so);
3.  'apxs' is not in your path.  Try to use --with-apxs=/path/to/apxs
The output of apxs follows
/tmp/tmpJQuZdD/APC-3.0.16/configure: line 3846: apxs: command not found
configure: error: Aborting
ERROR: `/tmp/tmpJQuZdD/APC-3.0.16/configure --with-apxs' failed
```

what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow. It belongs on ServerFault instead. Please see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The hint is `yum whatprovides *bin/apxs`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You forgot this package:

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel.i386
```

or

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel
```

You also might need:

```
apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
```

Once it's complete, try again and at the end restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k graceful
```